# Imperative Apex Flattening Limitation?

Tags: apex, lightning

I'm trying to put some relationship fields in a datatable. I know I need to flatten them, and I have zero issues doing this via wire, but whenever I try doing it via a button click with imperative apex, I can't get anything to even display in the console log. I've tried various approaches. Here's the most recent one:

```
handleFilterLoad() {
        filteredReports({entityId: this.entityId, selectedEntityId: this.selectedEntityId,selectedYearId: this.selectedYearId,selectedDocId: this.selectedDocId})
            .then((result) => {
                this.filteredReportData = result;
                this.allReports = [];

                if(result.data) {
                    for(let i=0; i<result.data.length;i++) {
                        let row = result.data[i];
                        this.allReports = [
                            ...this.allReports,
                            Object.assign(
                                {
                                    reportName: row.Name,
                                    reportEntity:row.Report_Status__r.Account__r.Name
                                },
                                row
                            )
                        ];
                    }
                    this.reports = this.allReports;
                    console.log(this.reports);
                }
                console.log(this.reports);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
                this.filteredReportData = undefined;
            });
    }
}
```

Nothing in my log.

I've also tried something like this:

```
let preparedReports = [];
            this.data = data;
            this.data.forEach(report => {
                let objectReports = {};
                objectReports.Id = report.Id;
                objectReports.Name = report.Name;
                objectReports.Entity = report.Report_Status__r.Account__r.Name;
                objectReports.Year = report.Report_Status__r.Name;
                objectReports.Number = report.Report__c;
                objectReports.Description = report.DescriptionShort__c;
                preparedReports.push(objectReports);
                window.console.log('this is' + preparedReports);
```

Also doesn't seem to work. The only thing I can get to actually display is:

```
handleFilterLoad() {
        filteredReports({entityId: this.entityId, selectedEntityId: this.selectedEntityId,selectedYearId: this.selectedYearId,selectedDocId: this.selectedDocId})
            .then((result) => {
                this.filteredReportData = result;
         
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
                this.filteredReportData = undefined;
            });
    }
```

Which is expected, given the simplicity.

What's wrong with my approach here? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code? Put a breakpoint in and run it just after you get the result back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For imperative calls, there is no "data" or "error". If you get data, you get to the `.then` block, otherwise you hit the `.catch` block.

```
.then((result) => {
  this.filteredReportData = result.map((objectReport) => ({
    ...objectReport,
    Entity: objectReport.Report_Status__r.Account__r.Name,
    Year: objectReport.Report_Status__r.Name,
    Number: objectReport.Report__c,
    Description: objectReport.DescriptionShort__c,
  }));
})
.catch((error) => {this.error = error});
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the assistance.